# Subclassing LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a problem trying to create a subclass of LinearLayout. I have a simple fragment with this layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map_container"
            >

    <!-- Map view -->
    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_map_map_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"/>


    <!-- Record description -->
    <com.example.SmallRecordDetailsWidget
        android:id="@+id/fragment_map_record_detail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</FrameLayout>
```

The SmallRecordDetailsWidget is a subclass of LinearLayout.
My problem is that I can't find the right way to instantiate/inflate it.

Here's what my SmallRecordDetailsWidget looks like now

```
public class SmallRecordDetailsWidget extends LinearLayout {


    private final int layoutID = R.layout.small_record_details;

    public SmallRecordDetailsWidget(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(this.layoutID, this, true) ;

    }


}
```

Then in fragment's onCreateView I'm doing:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup containter, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, containter, false) ;

        this.mapView = (MapView)( view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_map_map_view) );
        this.recordDetailsWidget = (SmallRecordDetailsWidget)( view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_map_record_detail) ) ;

        return view;

    }
```

But this codes brakes on `View view = inflater.inflate(...)` with

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.lexues.android.hari_prototype.views.SmallRecordDetailsWidget
```

which I can track to being thrown on

`LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(this.layoutID, this, true) ;`

line from `SmallRecordDetailsWidget`'s constructor. Inflater fails even on dead simple layout, like this one

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <!-- A widget with details of selected point of interest. This will be placed at the bottom of the map widget -->
    <com.lexues.android.hari_prototype.views.SmallRecordDetailsWidget xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/small_record_details_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="82dp">

    </com.lexues.android.hari_prototype.views.SmallRecordDetailsWidget>
```

Now, I've stripped my problem to smallest case that reproduces the issue, so it looks like I'm not doing anything useful here, but the goal is for `SmallRecordDetailsWidget` to have a few simple member widgets and then do a bit of work with them. If I understand correctly as long as they would be defined within layout file that `SmallRecordDetailsWidget`'s constructor inflates (as children of the root element) then they should also get inflated, so that I can later on get hold of them with `findViewById(...)`.

---

Edit - added stack trace and a bit of extra details

The stack trace is:

```
        09-01 09:24:18.661    6330-6330/com.lexues.android.hari_prototype E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.lexues.android.hari_prototype, PID: 6330
        android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.lexues.android.hari_prototype.views.SmallRecordDetailsWidget
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
        at com.lexues.android.hari_prototype.controllers.fragments.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:87)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:478)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:382)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2505)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2175)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1316)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1513)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6401)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                    at com.lexues.android.hari_prototype.controllers.fragments.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:87)
                    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:478)
                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365)
                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365)
                    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:382)
                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365)
                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2505)
                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2175)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1316)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1513)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1200)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6401)
                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
        at com.lexues.android.hari_prototype.views.SmallRecor
        09-01 09:24:19.381     882-6350/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
        09-01 09:24:20.361      267-267/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
```

As noted in the code I posted, in the constructor of `SmallRecordDetailsWidget` I inflate layout `R.layout.small_record_details`, where `small_record_details.xml` is the xml that defines the widget (while `com.lexues.android.hari_prototype.views.SmallRecordDetailsWidget` is the name of its root tag).

And just to make my goals clear - I want to create a widget that contains a few others. I hope to define all of them in the xml for that 'compound widget', then in costructor get references to child widgets, so that client can do things like `SmallRecordDetailsWidget.titleTextWidget.setText(...)`, etc.

Comment: What's the full stacktrace, including any nested "caused by" exceptions? Does the `small_record_details` layout recursively inflate the same `SmallRecordDetailsWidget` class?

Comment: why do you call LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(this.layoutID, this, true) ; in the ctor?

Comment: Can you post the names of the Layouts? You might be inflating the wrong thing or in the wrong way, but I need the names to tell

Comment: My answer applies if your last layout is layout/small_record_details.xml. I guesses that from the fact you named similarly its id. Anyway, if you post the layout's names I can say for sure

Comment: Added the edits.
@pskink - Because I need to inflate it? What seems to be wrong with that line?

Comment: @pskink - well, with the `SmallRecordDetailsWidget` I showed it's actually not required, I admit that. But my goal is to put some widgets inside it and I thought I need to inflate the layout to have them inflated too. Otherwise when I tried getting references to them through findByID they were all null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after more digging with better keyword (googling for `custom View` instead of `extending ViewGroup`), this article helped me:
http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-create-compound-controls-for-android/

My problem was that I used `com.lexues.android.hari_prototype.views.SmallRecordDetailsWidget` as the name of the root element of the layout which defined my custom widget. I should had simply used `LinearLayout` or any other layout as desired. Which makes sense come to think of it, otherwise I'm referencing the element before finishing defining it. Silly me.

Comment: That is exactly my answer, what did you find unclear? Anyway, I'd use a <merge> as the root of the view hierarchy that you attach to your custom layout. Otherwise you have a SmallRecordDetailsWidget (that is a LinearLayout) with a unique LinearLayout child, which is useless

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I understand it only reading it now that know my custom tag references the class that inflates my custom layout, not the layout itself. That's the bit that confused me.
A valid point about the merge, too.

Answer (score 4):

Reading your question it seems your are inflating the **wrong layout** in `SmallRecordDetailsWidget`'s constructor.

There, you should NOT use the tag

```
<com.lexues.android.hari_prototype.views.SmallRecordDetailsWidget>
```

You use that tag when you are inflating/instatiating the custom layout from your fragment, but NOT when you are inflating a small view hierarchy and attach it to your custom layout. The view hierarchy should not contain that tag, try putting something like a TextView in layout/small_record_details.xml